# Workbench fails to run on OSX. Reports "Front end could not be launched."

Tags: mac-os-x, workbench

I've just installed Workbench 2.0 and I am trying to use it with Mathematica 10.

Following the examples in the help I created the sample Test project.

When I hit run it does the following.

- Spawns a new Mathematica app.
- Opens a blank notebook.
- Workbench sits on 19% for about a minute.

After that I get the following error message.

[image: The Mathematica Notebook front end could not be launched.]

I have reinstalled Mathematica + Workbench from scratch but still the same.

Also the blank notebook spawned is not in the `Directory[]` for the code. So that's a bit pointless.

---

As a workaround I have Mathematica launched and I've manually SetDirectory[] to my project, but it just seems a bit annoying I can't just work out of the workbench.

Comment: So, is there anything at the location indicated? ie, if you type `/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/Mathematica` into a terminal window, does it launch Mathematica? Presumably yes, since it does get launched, but worth checking.

Comment: There's a thread about this on Wolfram Community.  Take a look.  Today it takes an extremely long time to load so I didn't look it up for you.

Comment: @acl yep the location is correct and launches.

Comment: @Szabolcs. I'll try find that, but if you get the link before me please post. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a known issue with the Workbench.

http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/291822?_19

From that link the suggestion is to contact support:

(Bruce)

> You are not the first people to encounter a problem launching
>   Mathematica 10 from recent Wolfram Workbench. It seems to be erratic
>   as to which computers and which projects.
>
> Requests; please send this information to support@wolfram.com:
>
> 1) Under the Wolfram Workbench menu, About Wolfram Workbench item, the
>   window shows a version number. Please send that. Also send the "Build"
>   number if one is shown.
>
> 2) Try changing the path to Mathematica in the Workbench preferences
>   from Default to the explicit full path. Do this even if the default
>   value shown is correct. This is known to have helped in one case.
>   Include in your email whether this helped.
>
> 3) The actual text of the error message, if any, and the symptoms.
>
> 4) And of course, please include the Mathematica license number or
>   Activation Key and the operating system level.

I've logged a support request. So if I get a solution I will post here.

Comment: So you found it. Sorry for not giving the link. At the time I was in a hurry and Community didn't load in half a minute.